# I Want to get the total of row using mysql query

Tags: mysql

i want to get the total sum of row in one query

```
(SELECT 
SUM(vatPrivate) AS vatPrivate,
SUM(vatGovernment) AS vatGovernment,
SUM(vatZero) AS vatZero,
SUM(vatExempt) AS vatExempt,
SUM(vatPrivate+vatGovernment+vatZero+vatExempt) as VatTotal
FROM transaction gl
WHERE (gl.entryDate) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2020-01-31')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
SUM(vatPrivate+vatGovernment+vatZero+vatExempt)
```

To

```
COALESCE(SUM(vatPrivate),0) + COALESCE(SUM(vatGovernment),0) +COALESCE(SUM(vatZero),0) + COALESCE(SUM(vatExempt),0) as VatTotal
```

**Note**: NULL + Some Value = NULL so if any of the sum is coming null and you are not using `COALESCE`, you will get null as the output.

Your final query should look like following

```
SELECT 
SUM(vatPrivate) AS vatPrivate,
SUM(vatGovernment) AS vatGovernment,
SUM(vatZero) AS vatZero,
SUM(vatExempt) AS vatExempt,
COALESCE(SUM(vatPrivate),0) + COALESCE(SUM(vatGovernment),0) +COALESCE(SUM(vatZero),0) + COALESCE(SUM(vatExempt),0) as VatTotal
FROM transaction gl
WHERE (gl.entryDate) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
```

Comment: i try this query but the result is null in vattotal

Comment: You need to use COALESCE or IFNULL

Comment: oh Thank you very much , the query now get the vattotal